# C# Entity Framework: Can't create row with ID which was deleted before

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I've created some data to my database in Entity Framework, e.g. rows with unique IDs 1,2 and 3. Then I've deleted row with ID = 1 using

```
int selectedId = (int)ComboChoosePerson.SelectedValue;  // selected ID
person = db.Persons.First(p => p.Id == selectedId);  // find the person
db.Persons.Remove(person);  // remove from DB
db.SaveChanges();
```

And when I try to create a new row with ID = 1, it changes ID to 4, 5, 6, etc. I need to have access to all usable IDs. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is SQL functionality.  You shouldn't care what the ID of a row is as the database just uses this to track the content internally. The table provides the next available ID but does not recycle ID's already used - otherwise it wouldn't work. Your ID is just a tag to find a record in the table. Why would the ID matter to you i.e is there something you haven't put in your question that you think you should be doing with the ID?

Comment: The ID is also a Personal identification number of a person. If person starts working in company, then leaves and then starts working there again, I need to use the same ID for him.

Comment: You shouldnt delete the record if the user can return. If you have to delete the record you could move the user id to a different column and keep a record of this when they leave in a pending return table. I would use a guid for their id. You need to review your approach as deleting the user record does what it says on the tin and will delte all their data

Comment: Delete data, leave ID. That sounds acceptable. And it also won't be big change of a code. Thanks